# How to create custom scrollbar for TableView in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qt-creator

I want to customize the ScrollBar in a TableView.
I am able to customize the ScrollBar in ListView and GridView but I couldn't do the same with the TableView.

I found that this is because GridView and ListView inherit from the Flickable but TableView inherits from ScrollView. Is there any alternative for this?

```
TableView {
    id:songGrid
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "title"
        title: "Title"
        width: 100
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "author"
        title: "Author"
        width: 200
    }


    ScrollBar.horizontal:  ScrollBar {
        id: scrollBar2
        anchors.bottom:  songGrid.bottom
        //            anchors.bottomMargin: 70*downscaleFactor
        width: 5
        active: true
        visible:songGrid.moving?true:false

        contentItem: Rectangle {
            id:contentItem_rect2
            width:100
            implicitHeight:4
            radius: implicitHeight/2
            color: "Red"
        }
    }

    model: libraryModel1
}


ListModel {
    id: libraryModel1
    ListElement {
        title: "A Masterpiece"
        author: "Gabriel"
    }
    ListElement {
        title: "Brilliance"
        author: "Jens"
    }
    ListElement {
        title: "Outstanding"
        author: "Frederik"
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-scrollview) link if you use Qt Quick Controls 2 or [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-scrollviewstyle.html) one if not.

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a `ScrollBar`, put it where ever you want. Then you bind the `songGrid.flickableItem.contentX/Y` to the `ScrollBar.position` in the correct way. If the `TableView` can be moved by other means then the `ScrollBar` you need to use a second `Binding` to update the `position` in those cases.

This is a short sketch-up in which I only account for the direction: `ScrollBar -> TableView` (add it to the code from your Question).

```
Binding {
    target: songGrid.flickableItem
    property: "contentY"
    value: (songGrid.flickableItem.contentHeight + 16) * vbar.position - (16 * (1 - vbar.position))
}

ScrollBar {
    id: vbar
    z: 100
    orientation: Qt.Vertical
    anchors.top: songGrid.top
    anchors.left: songGrid.right
    anchors.bottom: songGrid.bottom
    active: true
    contentItem: Rectangle {
        id:contentItem_rect2
        radius: implicitHeight/2
        color: "Red"
        width: 10 // This will be overridden by the width of the scrollbar
        height: 10 // This will be overridden based on the size of the scrollbar
    }
    size: (songGrid.height) / (songGrid.flickableItem.contentItem.height)
    width: 10
}
```

You can see those *mysterious* `16` in the `Binding`. This is some offset that is needed, probably to account for the horizontal ScrollBar. This might be different for different styles/platforms.

> If you have further questions, please ask a new question. If you only need more clarification, place a comment.

Comment: thanks this seems working but how can i disable the default scrollbar and also mouse scroll isn't working in this case.Is there a way we could style the default scrollbar?also i need those up down button in scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Qt Quick Controls Styles QML Types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-controls-styles-qmlmodule.html) to change the  appearance of scrollbar.

`TableView` has an `style` attribute inherit from `ScrollView`. To customize the scrollbar, just override it.

Here is a simple example.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

TableView {
    id: songGrid
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "title"
        title: "Title"
        width: 100
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "author"
        title: "Author"
        width: 200
    }
    model: libraryModel1
    style: TableViewStyle {
        handle: Rectangle {
            implicitHeight: 17
            color: "red"
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: libraryModel1
        ListElement {
            title: "A Masterpiece"
            author: "Gabriel"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Brilliance"
            author: "Jens"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
    }
}
```

You can also change the background of scorllbar, appearance of increment/decrement button... etc. For more information, please refer to 
[ScrollViewStyle QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-scrollviewstyle.html)(The parent class of `TableViewStyle`)

BTW, if you want to create a new scrollbar as `derM` said, you can set `horizontalScrollBarPolicy` or `verticalScrollBarPolicy` to 
`Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff` to disable default scrollbar.These two property were both from [ScrollView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html)