# scroll bar in tableView

Tags: qml, tableview, scrollbar

i have this code for a Table View, the table have 40 rows with data but when i use the scroll bar it doesn't go all the way down and i don't know why, and also it changes its position as far as it goes depending on the number of rows
i want to go from top to the bottom for every numbers of rows
P.S. when i open the table i see the first 11 rows, so for rows > 11 the scroll bar should move, if the number of rows in less than 11 i want that the scroll bar to be invisible

````
TableView {
        id: tableView
        //anchors.fill: tableImg
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 115
        anchors.bottomMargin: 85
        anchors.rightMargin: 55
        anchors.leftMargin: 55

        backgroundVisible: false
        clip: true
        verticalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn
        horizontalScrollBarPolicy: horizontalScrollBar;
        flickableItem.flickableDirection : Flickable.HorizontalAndVerticalFlick

        property int rowHeight: scrMgr.size.height * 40 / 1080
        property int startYContent: 0
        property int topYcontent: tableView.flickableItem.contentY
        property int topRow: topYcontent + tableView.rowAt(5,tableView.startYContent + 5) - topYcontent //keep add and substract in order to have active bindings

        onTopRowChanged: {
            console.log("topRoww: " + topRow);
        }

        resources:
        {
            var length = columns.length
            var temp = []
            for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                temp.push(columnComponent.createObject(tableView, {"role": columns[i].role, "title": columns[i].title}));
            }

            return temp
        }

        model: scancardimg.model

        style: TableViewStyle {

            incrementControl: Rectangle {
                visible: false
            }

            decrementControl: Rectangle {
                visible: false
            }

            handle: Rectangle {
                x:0
                y:0
                color: "transparent"
                border.color: "transparent"
                CustomImage {
                    source: resMgr.getResource("qrc:/Images/Slider/Sliderdot.svg")
                    implicitWidth: scrMgr.size.width * 0.0364//35
                    implicitHeight: implicitWidth
                    utilBox {t_left: 20; t_right: 20; t_top: 18; t_bottom: 22;}
                    Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; color: "#00000000"; border.color: "yellow"; border.width: 1;}
                }
            }

            scrollBarBackground: Rectangle {
                id: control
                implicitWidth: scrMgr.size.width * 0.0364 //35
                color: "transparent"
                border.color: "transparent"
                CustomImage {
                    source: resMgr.getResource("qrc:/Images/Slider/Sliderbar.svg")
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    utilBox {t_left: 0; t_right: 0; t_top: 2.3; t_bottom: 5;}
                    Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; color: "#00000000"; border.color: "yellow"; border.width: 1;}
                }
            }

            frame: Rectangle {
                color: "#00000000"
                border.color: "#00000000"
            }

            alternateBackgroundColor: "#00000000"

            itemDelegate: Item {
                x: scrMgr.size.width * 0.0084 //8
                y: scrMgr.size.width * 0.002 //8
                height: tableView.rowHeight //19
                Text {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    color: styleData.textColor
                    elide: styleData.elideMode
                    text: styleData.value
                    font.pixelSize: scrMgr.size.height * 0.028
                    visible: tableView.topRow >= 0 ? (styleData.row >= tableView.topRow) : true
                }
            }

            rowDelegate: Rectangle{
                width: childrenRect.width
                height: tableView.rowHeight
                color: "#00000000";
            }

            headerDelegate: Rectangle {
                id: headerComp
                height: textItem.implicitHeight * 1.2 + scrMgr.size.height * 0.0277 //15
                width: textItem.implicitWidth
                color: "#00000000";

                Text {
                    id: textItem
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    font.pixelSize: scrMgr.size.height * 0.028
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    horizontalAlignment: styleData.textAlignment
                    anchors.leftMargin: scrMgr.size.width * 0.0084 //8
                    anchors.topMargin: scrMgr.size.height * 0.015 //8
                    text: styleData.value
                    color: "white"
                }

                Component.onCompleted: {
                    tableView.startYContent = headerComp.y + headerComp.height;
                }
            }
        }
    }```
the scroll bar looks like this
[![picture_of_table][1]][1]
and i want to go all the way down when i scroll the table



  [1]: https://imgur.com/a/xlOtI0H
````

Comment: First question: Why do you try to create and handle an own scroll bar? How about using 
ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{} for your TableView?

Comment: i need to be a custom scroll bar

Comment: You should use [QtQuick Controls 2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-tableview.html) if possible and follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770870/how-to-create-custom-scrollbar-for-tableview-in-qml

Comment: you can customize by modifying what's inside `ScrollBar {}` in what Jürgen wrote. Also it seems your are using TableView from Qt Quick Controls 1 which hasn't been supported for a while and it was a mess to begin with.